# How do I match request.getParameterValues with mybatis for List? String[]? or List<String>?

Tags: java, arrays, list, request, mybatis

I am trying to send an array from front end using Angular JS so in my back end I have used request.parameter() command (which is used for String). 
For list I can use `request.getParametersValues()` but it is used for `String[]`, not for `List<String>`. On the other hand, if I use `String[]` then in mybatis `javaType="java.util.List" cannot match with String[]`.
Is there a specific javaType for `String[]`?

Attempt 1 
java

```
private List<String> values;

dataService.post(request.getParametersValues("values"); -> error here (cannot match with List<String>)
```

mybatis

```
<resultMap id="value_input" type="values">
<result property="values" column="VALUES" javaType="java.util.List"/> 
</resultMap>
```

Attempt 2 
java

```
private String[] values;

dataService.post(request.getParametersValues("values");
```

mybatis

```
<resultMap id="value_input" type="values">
<result property="values" column="VALUES" javaType="java.util.List"/> -> error here (cannot match with String[])
</resultMap>
```

Comment: As a side comment to my answer, the code you put in the question doesn't compile. Take a minute to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to assign an array (`String[]`) to a list (`List<String>`).

What you can do is to convert the array of values retrieved from the request to a list of String using the following instruction:

```
List<String> value = Arrays.asList(request.getParametersValues("values"));
```

This will allow you to use the first attempt code.